# MAUI Blazor Navigation Manager does not stay on the second page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor, maui

Currently I’m developing MAUI application with blazor template.I use the navigation manager to navigate to another page in order to move to the next page when a user successfully enters their credentials.

Navigation manager moves me to the next page. But in a millisecond, it will be redirected to the index page.

Here is my index code below:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation;

<div class="center_div" >
    <form class="center_content">
        <center>
            <h3 class="login_title">Sign In</h3>
            <p class="login_text">Login with your Credentials</p>
            <div class="field_cont">
                <input type="text" class="field_input" placeholder=" " />
                <label class="field_label">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="field_cont">
                <input type="password" class="field_input" placeholder=" " />
                <label class="field_label">Password</label>
            </div>
            <button @onclick="()=>NavigateToCompany()" class="form_btn">Sign In</button>
        </center>
    </form>
</div>


@code{
    private string UserName = "";
    private string Password = "";

    private void NavigateToCompany()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/company-select");
    }
}
```

Here is my second page code below:

```
@page "/company-select"

<h3>CompanySelect</h3>

@code {

}
```

How can I stay on second page rather than be redirected to the index page?

I use **.NET 7** and **Visual studio 2022**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `Button` element outside the form element like below:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation;

<div class="center_div"> 

    <form class="center_content">

        <center>

            <h3 class="login_title">Sign In</h3>

            <p class="login_text">Login with your Credentials</p>

            <div class="field_cont">

                <input type="text" class="field_input" placeholder=" " />

                <label class="field_label">Username</label>

            </div>

            <div class="field_cont">

                <input type="password" class="field_input" placeholder=" " />

                <label class="field_label">Password</label>

            </div>

        </center>

    </form>

    <button @onclick="()=>NavigateToCompany()" class="form_btn">Sign In</button>

</div>
```

```
@code{
    private string UserName = "";
    private string Password = "";

    private void NavigateToCompany()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/company-select");
    }
}
```

The reason why you need place the button outside of the form is that when putting a button element inside a form element, the attribute of the button element defaults to `submit` leading to that it will be redirected to the index.